# How to resolve SQL error when fetching data from a foreign data table in Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, freetds, foreign-data-wrapper

I have a foreign data table created with `tds_fdw` which maps a SQL View on an MSSQL server to a foreign table in Postgres. I can view and query the data in this table without any issue. But I'm getting this error when I try to query this table from a query which is joining the foreign table and several other tables.

Error is:

```
[2020-07-28 14:04:25] [HV00L] ERROR: DB-Library error: DB #: 20018, DB Msg: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server, OS #: -1, OS Msg: , Level: 15
[2020-07-28 14:04:25] [00000] DB-Library notice: Msg #: 156, Msg state: 1, Msg: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'., Server: DB1DBSSVR1, Process: , Line: 1, Level: 15
```

This is how the SQL query looks like

```sql
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM (
    SELECT a.COL1, b.COL2, c.COL3 FROM 
        PSQL_TABLE_1 a JOIN PSQL_TABLE_2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
        JOIN FOREIGN_TABLE f on b.ID = f.CODE WHERE a.COL5 = 'S'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.COL1, b.COL2, c.COL3 FROM 
        PSQL_TABLE_1 a JOIN PSQL_TABLE_3 b ON a.ID = b.ID
        JOIN FOREIGN_TABLE f on b.ID = f.CODE WHERE a.COL5 = 'S'
) 
DERIVED WHERE DERIVED.SEQ_NO = 'xxxx'
```

**Note**
Earlier this query used a local pg table which had the same name and structure as the foreign table and was working fine. This issue started after renaming it and creating the new foreign table with the same name and structure

Comment: Where is this query being run, on SQL Server or Postgres? Also the error says:```Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.``` and there is no ```as``` in the query you show. Is this coming from the view query? Also which log are you getting errors from?

Comment: @Adrian Query is executed on Postgres. The error is coming from the query that I've show. I'm getting this error from Postgres log. I'm running tds_fdw with log messages enabled

Comment: Well the error is clear that the problem is near the ```as``` keyword. I see no ```as``` in the query. So are you sure you did not edit it out when you anonymized the query? Also did you check the SQL Server log as the message suggests?

Comment: See answer for another explanation.

Comment: Which tool are you using to run that query?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That's what confuses me also. The anonymized query has the same structure as my original query. Earlier this query used a local pg table which had the same name and structure as the foreign table and was working fine. All I did was renaming it and creating the new foreign table with the same name and structure.

I'm unable to check SQL server logs as I don't have access to the client's server. Client only provided these views. I'm trying to get the logs emailed to me so I can figure out the exact cause

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm running this using DataGrip

Comment: @Isuru Pathirana . Pretty sure this has to do with running through ```tds_fdw```, more so now that you say running it all locally worked.  Per my comment below, have you tried renaming ```DERIVED``` to something like ```DERIVED_TABLE```?

Answer (score 0):

Aah, now I see. Pretty sure it is this:

`DERIVED WHERE DERIVED.SEQ_NO = 'xxxx'`.

`DERIVED` is a keyword and there is an implied `as` before it. Change that alias to another name or quote it.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a problem in SQL Server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3c5e1e817cb8011fce44512b4f5d5296

Comment: I follow the advice here:https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-keywords-appendix.html  "As a general rule, if you get spurious parser errors for commands that contain any of the listed key words as an identifier you should try to quote the identifier to see if the problem goes away." Or I change the name.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to be a problem for Postgres either: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3c5e1e817cb8011fce44512b4f5d5296

Comment: Remember this is being fed through ```tds_fdw```.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. But it seems neither side has a problem with that. Which only leaves tds_fdw as a possible reason why an additional `as` is added to the query. But it could also be the query tool. Wouldn't be the first one that tries to be smart and adds stuff to a query without the user knowing

Comment: I tried adding `as` there. But it makes no difference

Comment: Have you tried renaming ```DERIVED``` to something like ```DERIVED_TABLE```?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver yes I did but there's no change. But I think I found the cause. The query began to work once I trimmed the ID in the join clause. The error message is gone now and the query is working as expected. However, I have a new issue now. Now the DB is raising due to a segfault when sending multiple requests to that view. I'll add that as a new question

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was due to some data values in the fields I was using for the joins. The error went away once I trimmed the data. The new query looks something like,

```sql
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM (
    SELECT a.COL1, b.COL2, c.COL3 FROM 
        PSQL_TABLE_1 a JOIN PSQL_TABLE_2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
        JOIN FOREIGN_TABLE f on btrim(b.ID) = f.CODE WHERE a.COL5 = 'S'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.COL1, b.COL2, c.COL3 FROM 
        PSQL_TABLE_1 a JOIN PSQL_TABLE_3 b ON a.ID = b.ID
        JOIN FOREIGN_TABLE f on btrim(b.ID) = f.CODE WHERE a.COL5 = 'S'
) 
DERIVED WHERE DERIVED.SEQ_NO = 'xxxx'
```

This query is returning values as expected. But I'm still wondering why did it give an error saying there is a syntax error near `as`.

Comment: That is just weird. By any chance is there ```as``` in ```ID```? Otherwise I don't know why the syntax error.

Comment: The only thing I can think to do, if you have not already, is change ```log_statement``` in postgresql.conf to ```all``` and reload server.  Then run both variations of query and see what is being sent to server. Then set ```log_statement``` back.